# Cannot access class constant from class method?

Tags: class, methods, constants, undefined-reference

When I try to run the following PHP code, I get the error message and output below the code:

```
<?php

class FooBar {

  const MESSAGE = "Hello world!";

  public function foo() {

    echo MESSAGE;

  }

}

$fooBar = new FooBar;

$fooBar->foo();

?>
```

**Notice**:  Use of undefined constant MESSAGE - assumed 'MESSAGE' in **C:\xampp\htdocs\foo.php** on line **9**
MESSAGE

How do I solve the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is the solution to the problem:

```
<?php

class FooBar {

  const MESSAGE = "Hello world!";

  public function foo() {

    echo self::MESSAGE;

  }

}

$fooBar = new FooBar;

$fooBar->foo();

?>
```

OUTPUT: Hello world!

Regards!